# Following is the error produced when I try to install "mysql-python" in pycharm. Any help would be great

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Specifications:

- mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the module mysql-connector-python which is the official Python driver for MySQL. The latest release of mysql-python was in 2014, and it supports Python 3.9 no more.